# Changing attached class library symbols on the fly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, parallax

I am doing an assignment at university where I must make a game using flash.

There are several constraints:

1. No more than 5 classes (not including Main)
2. No arrays (Although we are allowed to use sprites as containers which gives us the functionality of a display object array).
3. No timeline scripting

I have decided to make a 2D side scrolling shooter, much like R-Type Leo (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjRAYV0jHBE).

The classes I have so far are:

Main, BaseObject, Ship, Bullet, Enemy, BG1, BG2, BG3

I have created 3 png files which have transparent backgrounds and are covered in white dots (stars), each of these png files is a different width so I can use them for parallax scrolling. I then imported the png's and converted them to library symbols. Each of the 3 symbols is then attached to a seperate class.

My problem is that I have to have 3 BG (Background) classes, is there any way I can use 1 class to display 3 seperate library symbols or does it have to be a class for each symbol?

I have a solution if I cannot change library symbols on the fly; I will only have 1 background library symbol and will use the Sprite properties to change the scale/rotation/position etc to give the effect of parralax.

Finally I heard there is a way to manipulate library symbols without having them actually attached to a class, ie. I could just place the symbols onto the stage in the fla file and manipulate them from main without actually having to have a BG class at all, if so how can this be achieved and is it bad practice?

Comment: I should probably add:

I have tried going into the properties of the 3 background symbols and entering the same "Base Class" name for each of them. But when I try to instantiate them now it says:

"No default constructor found in base class Classes:BG"
 
This is very odd as their is a constructor and I've triple checked the code, it's definitely correct...

Comment: why I not create a single BG class with 3 (or more) static properties which are the loaded assets ?

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that I have to have 3 BG (Background) classes, is there any way I can use 1 class to display 3 seperate library symbols or does it have to be a class for each symbol?

Just create a MovieClip and put all your backgrounds on different frames. Then use `gotoAndStop` for each instance to have it display different background.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with procedural backgrounds. For example generate some simple background (covered in white dots) by using [Graphics](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html).

> I could just place the symbols onto the stage in the fla file and manipulate them

Yes, you can. You could create several symbols in the library, and place them offscreen (top-left zone, if you will use `stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;`) or you could toggle visibility (mySceneAsset.visible = true|false). And don't forget to assign some names, so you will be able access them - `var someAsset: DisplayObject = getChildByName("someBackground1");` But I would go with procedural backgrounds, because It's very simple game for the university.

Comment: Thankyou. I've placed the symbols directly onto the stage in the fla and manipulated them from main to make my paralax :-)

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I have to have 3 BG (Background) classes, is there
>   any way I can use 1 class to display 3 seperate library symbols or
>   does it have to be a class for each symbol?

You can load the images externally

http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/